# Is there a $C^{*}$ algebra with these properties

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, noncommutative-geometry

Is there a unital C* algebra  A which is NOT simple but satisfies the following two conditions:

1)A has trivial center

2)A has a faithful trace such that every zero trace element lies in the closure of the  span of commutator elements.

By a commutator element I mean an element in the form xy-yx.

For  a  related MO post see [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/66343/commutators-in-the-reduced-c-algebra-of-the-free-group)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes** and you don't even have to take the closure. For instance if $A$ is a non-simple C*-algebra with trivial cetnre that has unique (faithful) trace (for instance $A=C^*(G)$ for a sufficiently non-commutative amenable group such as the group of permutations of integers that move at most finitely many entries), then $A\otimes \mathcal{Z}$, where $\mathcal{Z}$ is the Jiang-Su algebra, has the property that each zero-trace element is a sum of 7 commutators. This is a [nice result of Ng and Robert](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1504.00046.pdf).

Actually for most *nice* C*-algebras we have $A\otimes \mathcal{Z}\cong A$.

The result concerning taking the closure is easier and it does not involve the Jiang-Su algebra. See Robert's answer [here](https://mathoverflow.net/a/67899/15129).

Comment: thank you very much for your interesting and helpful answer.

Comment: @mathrookie, trivial centre usually means $\mathbb{C}\cdot 1_A$, which is the case here.